# Set up graphic interface (desktop) for remote connection

Tags: shell, centos, gui, remote-desktop

I was assigned a CentOS VM that I manipulate through Putty.  Everything I do to it is by command line so far, and I have admin rights to it.  The VM is stored in the corporate data center served up by VMWare.  There is no desktop environment installed at all.

My question: can I run a graphical environment remotely on my local machine (currently Windows 7) to configure and interact with this virtual server?  If yes, what do I do to set it up?

I realize that "real" admins use command prompt all the time, but that's not my primary job.  I'm just trying to make things a little easier for myself.

Comment: How about this?: https://www.nomachine.com/

Comment: @coffeMug Will that work if there's no desktop installed on the CentOS box?

Comment: If you really mean graphical desktop, it has to be installed on the target machine. 
Some graphical tools can be used w/o desktop, but at least X server software have to be installed though. In the latter case you can have X server running on your windows client and use X forwarding. If that's an option for you, I can provide some more how-to details

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install a desktop environment, e.g. `yum install gnome-desktop`.  Then you can install freenx ( `yum install freenx` ) and then run `/usr/bin/nxsetup` after the packages have been installed.  A freely available Windows NX client is available here: [OpenNX Client Downloads](http://opennx.net/download.html).

Other remote solutions include xrdp and tigervnc-server, which use the Microsoft RDP and VNC protocols respectively.  FreeNX is in the extras repo, xrdp is in [the EPEL repo](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), and tigervnc-server is in the updates repo.  (updates and extras, I believe are included in CentOS by default, while EPEL is not.)

Comment: There is a clear indication in the question that "There is no desktop environment installed at all"